# Bluemix SAML and timeout session issue

Tags: single-sign-on, web.xml, ibm-cloud, session-timeout, saml-2.0

I've created Web Application running on Java Liberty Runtime on Bluemix. Login is done by using [SSO](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/SingleSignOn/index.html#sso_gettingstarted) service with [SAML enterprise provider](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/configure_service.html#task_saml_is). After login user redirected to my app and on every JAX-RS request I get user's credentials by following code:

```
    Subject s = WSSubject.getCallerSubject();     
    Object credential = s.getPrivateCredentials().iterator().next();
    String loginToken = credential.toString();
```

Everything works fine, but if the user has been idle for more then 10 minutes and then perform any ajax request `WSSubject.getCallerSubject()` returns `null`, and I required to refresh application.

I've tried to increase timeout by adding following attribute to `web.xml`:

```
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

But it didn't help. So I'm looking how can I increase timeout or possible I can retrieve user credentials in a different way?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the optional element `<authCache>` to the `server.xml` file to change the default values for the authentication cache.

As you mentioned in your question, the default value is 10 minutes. To change it to 60 minutes you need to include the following in the `server.xml` file:

```
<authCache initialSize="50" maxSize="25000" timeout="60m"/>
```

The documentation [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_sec_cache.html) provides more details and also explains `initialSize` and `maxSize` options, I left the default value for these two above and just updated `timeout`.

If you are deploying your application using the default method of pushing the war file, you will need to use a different approach to deploy the application with a custom `server.xml` file. Please check the documentation [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#optionsforpushinglibertyapplications) for options on pushing Liberty profile applications (more specific check sections **Server Directory** and  **Packaged Server**).

In this case, you may also want to check the `server.xml` file that is currently deployed and modify that version to add the `<authCache>` element.

You can get a copy of the file by running the following command:

```
$ cf files <your_app_name> app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml
```

Comment: As 'files' command is not available in diego, server.xml can be obtained by 'cf ssh <your_app_name> -c "cat ./app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml"'